# statusnet - Refresh Page content after time interval

Tags: statusnet

Installed statusnet 1.0.1. & able to run it.

Now the enchantments I am looking for is :
page content reload after specific time interval. Right now I put header 'Refresh:50' in htmloutput.php file to reload entire page. But I want to update just timeline section, not entire page.

How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called `Realtime` included in the base distribution (`plugins/Realtime/`), you should check it out.

Comment: Yes got that. I try to use "Meteor", but no success. Do u have any success & can u share some steps/docs

Comment: I found it pretty well documented, but never actually installed it myself, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("DIV_TO_BE_REPLACED").load("PATH DIV_CLASS_OR_ID");
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
   $("DIV_TO_BE_REPLACED").load('PATH');
}, 9000);// change time limit
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

for example

```
$(".right").load("/index.html .right");
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
   $(".right").load('/index.html .right');
}, 3000);
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```